# Unable to use retrofit2 convertor

Tags: java, android, gson

So I'm trying to use retrofit GsonConvertorFactory but in the android studio, it is not reading because of which I'm unable to run.

```
    public class start {

            private  static final String id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            private  static final String url = "https://XXX/YY/ZZ";

            public static PostService postService = null;
            public static PostService getService()

            {
                if (postService == null) {
                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConvertorFactory.create()).build();
                    postService = retrofit.create((PostService.class));
                }
                return postService;
            }


        public interface PostService{
            @GET("?=id"+id )
            Call<PostDia> getPostDia();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? you did not clear that. Show `Error` messages or logs. Describe your problem with more context so anyone can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
```

to the build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that GsonConvertorFactory is only supported by 2.3.0 version and not any other version so try changing your dependencies

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'